# Deleting localstorage element via multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, local-storage

So i am using localStorage to add buttons to my html page. When the button is clicked, i want the corresponding entry of localStorage to be deleted.

My code so far:

```
for(let i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++)
    {
        var rem=document.createElement("button");
        rem.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        rem.setAttribute('background-color','white');
        rem.setAttribute('id',localStorage.key(i));
        rem.setAttribute('class','delbuttons');
        document.body.appendChild(rem);
    }
```

So if a button with a particular id is clicked, i want that corresponding key in localStorage to be deleted. I want the onclick for all buttons. 
So far what i have thought of is:

```
var delb=document.getElementsByClassName("delbuttons").addEventListener("click",del);
```

```
function del()
{
    localStorage.removeItem('key');
}
```

I am stuck here and i don't know how to proceed further. I am ok with alternative methods (jQuery is fine too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to Attach `onclick` event in `loop`:

```
rem.setAttribute("onclick","del(this)");
```

And function:

```
function del(x)
{
    localStorage.removeItem(x.id);
}
```

error part:
You are trying to add event on `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByTagName`, which is not possible.

You should add event on each element in  `HTMLCollection`. eg.

```
var delbs=document.getElementsByClassName("delbuttons");
for(var button of delbs){
    button.addEventListener("click",del(this));
}
function del(btm)
{
    localStorage.removeItem(btn.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit:

The API **getElementsByClassName** returns a collection of dom, you have to bind the listener on the real dom, e.g.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('delbuttons')).forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', del))
```

---

It looks like you were stucked by this topic: how to get the id of the button which is clicked now ?

There are several pieces of knowledge here.

1. Event listener (in your code is the function 'del') will receive an event object as the parameter. One of the important properties is [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) indicate the exact dom (in your code is the button you just clicked).
2. The dom API [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to visit defined properties, e.g. id of button

So we end up with a new version of del listener.

```js
    function del(event) {
      var id = event.target.getAttribute('id'); //or. var id = event.target.id
      localStorage.removeItem(id);
    }
```

Comment: ```var delb=document.getElementsByClassName("delbuttons").addEventListener("click",del);``` this part gives an error